# I am building react app with ag-grid and I am having an issue with trying how to put a link in the cell

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am building react app with ag-grid and I am having an issue with trying to figure out how to put a link in the cell and the link data being fetched on REST api response. Can anybody help me with that issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cellRenderer` property of `ColDef` for this.

Assuming that your field name is `url`, your `ColDef` will be something like this.

```
{
  headerName: 'URL',
  field: 'url',
  cellRenderer: (data: any) => `<a href="${data.value}">${data.value}</a>`
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i also want to show multiple links / multiple row in single cell inside the ag- grid, is that possible to implement? am I following the correct approach or do i need to use html table ?

Comment: @pratyakshsudan - how would I answer that unless you show your code? BTW, you don't need to use html table. Reproduce your situation on plunk or stackblitz if you want exact solution to your problem. Go through [ask], how to create [mcve]